# MuleSoft : How can I process one message per minute from Anypoint MQ

Tags: mule, mq

I have a 20 messages in AnyPoint MQ and want to retrieve one message per minute.
I have tried this using prefetch but its not working.
Can anybody please let me know how can we achieve this

Comment: have you tried quartz connector?

Comment: @user3714601 :  NO. I have not tried quartz. I have tried with POLL. its working but even after 20 messages poll hitting to the queue